# your security settings have blocked a local application from running

Tags: java, html

i am try to run the applet from html while it is giving the above exception.i added the .class file in the same folder which contain html. 
i made java security from high to medium. 
this is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Mouse Drag</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="khaki">
<h1>Mouse Drag Example</h1>
        <applet code="com.nic/TwainExample.class" width="300" height="300" archive="scann.jar" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what if you make it to low?

Comment: there is no option like low medium is the least one

Comment: just for clarification purpose. what if you make it as low security, can your app run?